# FLOSS software that helps you remember a passhprase

Tags: windows, android, linux, open-source, memory-management

Currently I'm using a bad passphrase and would like to switch to [diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware).

However, the kinds of passhphrases I'll be generating won't be recoverable so I must remember them.

Is there any software that helps with this? It must be FLOSS, since I don't want my password manager or phone passphrases (for example) to be sent to some other computer without my knowing.

I'd imagine it'd be helpful if the software nagged you like those alarm clocks that make you solve puzzles, but instead of a puzzle you'd have to type your passphrase with only a partial reminder (or none whatsoever if your memory is good enough).
So basically something between [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) (flashcard software that tracks your level of memorization for each card) and [I can't wake up](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kog.alarmclock) (a nagging alarm clock for Android that makes you solve puzzles and math problems to stop the alarm)

I only have access to Windows, Linux and Android so it needs to run on these platforms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see you don't want password manager but have you considered using say Bitwarden which is open source and can be selfhosted. Additionally if you want to use it as a way to just remind you partially you could just make a note of the partial password or trigger instead of saving the password and that will do the trick.

Comment: Generally, if you can remember your password, it means it's a weak one. Just use a password manager and dont bother remembering it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any recommendations for diceware specifically or for apps that are focused on memorization (e.g. flashcard apps).

Honestly, I would just handle this in an offline Password Manager - I recommend KeePass 2.0. It runs on [Windows](https://keepass.info/download.html) (and can even be installed using [ninite](https://ninite.com/)), many popular Linux distributions such as Mint and Ubuntu have it available directly from their central repositories, and there is an [Android port](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android&hl=en_US) that works fine loading files from SD card (should work fine for internal mem too). It saves to local disk in kdbx file format and you could have a separate kdbx file with only passphrases if you are worried about separating them for your passwords for some reason.

In other words, it would meet your criteria of not being sent to other computers but not the implied criteria of nagging / tracking memorization levels. However, it does provide a field for notes inside of entries so you could manually track it by recording things like "{DATE} - correct" / "{DATE} - incorrect" / etc.